# How to delete all highlighted search results in vim without %s?

Tags: vim

I often have complex search patterns in vim. If I find the exact pattern, that matches, what I'm searching and want to delete all the matches, I have to go into command mode type `:%s/...//` with `...` being the complicated pattern.

Is there an easier way to delete all results of a search, without going through them one by one?

Comment: you need global replace like @L3viathan mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't completely completely without `:%s/..`, but without typing the pattern again:

`:%s///g`

If you leave the pattern empty, it will repeat the search. If that's something you do often, you can bind a key (sequence) to it.

Comment: I use this a lot but depending on the situation, I sometimes *paste* in the pattern using `<c-r>/`. When using the `:g` command and a searched range, that comes in handy. Also when viewing your command history, it's nice to see the complete search pattern.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely **need** to avoid %s you can use gn together with a macro. Something along the lines of:

`qq` - record macro to register q
`dgn` - remove selection
`n` - jump to next match
`q` - stop recording
`9999@q` - run macro 9999 times

I would not call this a good solution by any means (the by @L3viathan proposed %s without entering a search pattern is superior), but it resolves the question as stated.

Comment: I mainly wrote "without %s", because my main question about not repeating the pattern was hard to shorten. L3viathans answer is pretty much, what I was hoping for, but I'm waiting a bit for answers like yours, which actually answer the question in the title before making a decision. Thanks for taking the time to answer :)

Comment: Mainly responded for the sake of posterity. Happy vimming!